# Unable to open anything in VLC

Tags: vlc

i click play in VLC, with my cowboy bebop disc inserted, it recognizes it,makes a noise, then does nothing and gives me the option to hit play again. any ideas? Lubuntu 18.10

Comment: Is it a DVD disk? Install `libdvd-pkg` then.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `sudo apt install libdvd-pkg`

Comment: None of these answers helped, actually. I’m sorry. The system doesn’t even do anything noticeable when a dvd is inserted, besides the noise of it spinning up

Comment: The command that was suggested by @pilot do go through, but still nothing is being seen by he system for some reason